# Decimal point error german representation

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]I have a unique problem. I am trying to save a decimal value in a column. The column only takes the decimal pointer as ',' and not '.' So 0,85 is acceptable value but 0.85 is not..

after inserting 0,85 as decimal when i execute :

```
select case 
    when (11>=(5 * ,85))and(11<=(5*1,15)) 
    then 'Green'  else 'CHECK_FAILED' 
end from dual;
```

it fails saying 'ORA-00936: missing expression 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"'

Is there anyway to fix this error? because i want it to be able to run smoothly in all systems..

Comment: For constant values a `.` is the only valid decimal separator in SQL. The query as shown is completely independent of the current NLS settings. Please show us your _real_ and **complete** and the definition of the table you are inserting into

Comment: This query, with hardcoded values, works. The issue probably is in the columns that you are using in your real query, so please post the structure of the involved tables/columns and an extract of the real code that is giving error.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are saying. I suspect what you **may** be saying is that the query works as written, but if you **change** it to show  `,85` instead of `.85` in the second line of code, it fails. That would indeed be expected, and consistent with the specific error you got. In SQL, the comma, outside of quoted strings, is a syntactic element. `5 * ,85` is read as two expressions, `5 *  ` and `85`. The first one looks like a multiplication where the second factor is missing - so you get the error. As *a_horse* said, in numeric literals you can **only** use the decimal **point**.

Comment: [Documentation reference to back up what the others have said](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#sthref320).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The data type is NUMBER(18,5) and when i try to insert 0.85 into it instead of 0,85 it throws a ORA-01722 error.. : invalid number..  plus i inserted 0,85 as a number and it worked for me.. not really sure if 0.85 is the only valid notation..

Comment: @mathguy_: are you really sure? i inserted 0,85 as a number and it worked for me.. not really sure if 0.85 is the only valid notation.. actually inserting 0.85 is not working for me..

Comment: `0.85` or `.85` are the only correct ways of writing a constant number in a SQL statement. There must be something you are not telling us: http://imgur.com/a/bLNyW

Comment: @thealchemist - are you inserting a numeric literal `0,85`, or a string that represents a number in your region, `'0,85'`? The latter will work with German NLS numeric characters, the former will not ever work as NLS isn't relevant for a numeric literal. It's also possible your client is doing something odd if you're entering data in a grid, say, rather than doing an explicit `insert` statement.

Comment: How are you inserting data into the table? from IDE, or writing a `insert ` statement ? And what is your `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` value ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I attached a screen shot.. i hope it helps..

Comment: I don't understand the question. In your question you talk about a "column" that stores numbers. But the query that is failing does not references columns, it has a hard-coded, fixed value, either `.85` or `,85` or whatever. The two are not the same thing. Are you getting an error when you reference a column in a table? Then show the exact query you are using, and show how **that** fails.

Comment: @mathguy: I got that query from the main query after replacing the variables.. for example.. the main query was select case when x y z then green end from dual;.. i replaced x with 11, y with the operator >= and z with 0,85.. all the values from the table..

Comment: I still don't understand. You said the column in the table is of data type NUMBER. In the database, numbers are stored in a proprietary format that does not have either . or , (it has no decimal separator at all, since the internal format is in "exponent and mantissa" format). Your query is not "select case when x y z" - to help you, you must show exactly what x, y, and z are. Does the query fail when instead of the hard-coded number `,85` you have a column name, and the column is number data type? I don't quite believe it - prove me wrong!

Comment: thanks for all the support guys :) really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked when I changed the NLS session parameters to match with the database parameters. 
It was not working because the 'NLS session parameters' had different decimal representation than the 'NLS database parameters'..

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';
```

Answer (score 0):

In german you can not omit the 0 in front of a decimal value. Also you used a period instead of a comma. So ".85" should be "0,85" and "1.15" should be "1,15"

Comment: That's wrong. In SQL constants, you can **only** use the `.` regardless of the language:  http://imgur.com/a/e8Sb9

Comment: What will happen if you change `,85` to `0,85` is that the multiplication becomes `5*0`, and Oracle will throw another error because `11 >= (expr1, expr2)` is not a valid condition.